# Wining possibility for defense D00 - Queen's Pawn Game: Mason Attack from 15th move

Tags: analysis

Please have the game link over [here](https://lichess.org/Up33Ot2y#72).

I made my mistake not moving `...Nh4` with `...Nh4` as white I feel I do have the possibility of winning if I would've made.

```
[FEN "r2q1rk1/1pp1npp1/p2b2bp/3Q4/5P1N/P3P3/NP4PP/R1B2RK1 b - - 4 15"]
```

I had thought of this move, but I've slipped.

Please give us an analysis considering the move made by white.

**NO -**
[image]

I would step back with `...Qb3`

```
[FEN "r2q1rk1/1pp1npp1/p2b2bp/8/5P2/PQ2PN2/NP4PP/R1B2RK1 b - - 4 15"]
```

Answer (score 4):

15.Qb3 is much better than 15.Nh4??,an horrendous move that hangs the queen. After 15.Qb3 Black is slightly better but the game continues.

In the line hiven in the OP, Black counters 15.Nh4?? not by capturing the queen (15...Nxd5!) but with an even worse move, 15...Nf5??. Then you are given the opportunity to win a free bishop with 16.Nxg6 exploiting the pin of the Pf7, but well, the comedy of errors continues.

Your priority if you want to make progress should be to develop a habit of looking for possible checks and captures for both sides. If you stop hanging your pieces and punish your opponents when they do, you can expect to win more games.

Comment: 15.Nh4?? was not played in the actual game.

Comment: @DM Ah you're right. The text was a bit confusing...